# A lot of hazelcast members are created

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

Im doing testing in a way that I'm creating snapshot of test application in base class and test classes are extending it. There are some hazelcast related checks and when I see logs I see a lot of members which are created. The question is how to keep it stead and clean. Was trying to add

```
hazelcastInstance.getDistributedObjects().forEach(DistributedObject::destroy);
```

in @AfterClass block and others but still same,
is it a declerative way to set config in a way to stick with only one hazelcast member? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: How do you create the hazelcast instance? Do you shut it down in `@After` or `@AfterClass`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that test app has hazelcast instance in itself, and when Im making snapshot of the app not only test related member is started but member of app itself